# KnockoutMVC Foreach Lambda filter (or any filter)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I have been able to create a display that loops a list of pages.  This will display all pages in the DB table like the following.

```
@using (var page = ko.Foreach(m => m.PageList))
{
    @page.Html.TextBox(p => p.PageErrorMessage)
    @page.Html.TextBox(p => p.PageSuccessMessage)
    @page.Html.TextBox(p => p.Title)
    @page.Html.TextBox(p => p.Content)
}
```

I am would like to be able to filter what displays by a lambda expression on the Foreach.  Currently that returns the type IEnumerable, even with a ToList() at the end the following does not work.

```
//Note: I have tried .Where pl.Title == "string" with the same results
@using (var page = ko.Foreach(m => m.PageList.Where(pl => pl.Title.Contains("Page01")))
{
    @page.Html.TextBox(p => p.PageErrorMessage)
    @page.Html.TextBox(p => p.PageSuccessMessage)
    @page.Html.TextBox(p => p.Title)
    @page.Html.TextBox(p => p.Content)
}
```

I can get the results that I want, but it seems cumbersome to do this.  If I add a visible check to each field with the same check I only see the fields I want.

```
//Note: p.Title.Contains("string") does not work for me in the Visible here
@using (var page = ko.Foreach(m => m.PageList))
{
    @page.Html.TextBox(p => p.PageErrorMessage).Visible(p => p.Title == "Page01!")
    @page.Html.TextBox(p => p.PageSuccessMessage).Visible(p => p.Title == "Page01!")
    @page.Html.TextBox(p => p.Title).Visible(p => p.Title == "Page01!")
    @page.Html.TextBox(p => p.Content).Visible(p => p.Title == "Page01!")
}
```

Is there a better way to work with foreach to filter down the list or is this currently designed to always return the full set?

Comment: Not too familiar with knockout-mvc, but I am pretty sure you have to reference a computed list on the viewmodel. You can't use a C# lamba on the page, since it needs to be converted into javascript.

Comment: You are correct about the conversion to knockout js, but that does not mean it should not have some sort of filter.  Any type of filter would be acceptable, it does not need to be lambda.  It seems to me that if you have items in a database you would not always want to display them all. Perhaps something is inactive or even with a contact editor you might only want to pull up 5 at a time.

Comment: That would still need to be logic in the viewmodel, represented as a computed list.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  Sometimes you just have to step back and rethink things.  Place that as an answer I will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use C# code in razor to modify your viewmodel. To bind against something it needs a representation in the **viewmodel**. If you want to filter the full list, a `computed` property on the viewmodel should do the trick.

```
[Computed]
public List<Page> FilteredList
{
  get { return PageList.Where(pl => pl.Title.Contains("Page01")); }
}
```